# Derive positional Show

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, typeclass, template-haskell, deriving

Notice how `T 5` shows in

```
> newtype T = T { getT :: Int } deriving Show
> T 5
T {getT = 5}
```

Is there some way to derive the positional, non-record-syntax variant of Show for a type that was declared with record syntax?

(btw `T` is only a simple example to explain the question, I'm looking for a general answer for any type defined with record syntax)

Some options I would be satisfied with:

- TH generation for it provided by a library
- A `Generic` based derivation (where the manual instance refers to an existing function)
- An easy way / guide to manually implement `Show` instances
- Any other idea I didn't think about

For a more complicated example I have [this hand-written instance](https://github.com/lamdu/syntax-tree/blob/master/src/AST/Term/FuncType.hs#L34):

```
instance ... where
    showsPrec p (FuncType i o) =
        showParen (p > 0)
        (("FuncType " <>) . showsPrec 1 i . (" " <>) . showsPrec 1 o)
```

I would like the answer to be able to avoid this boilerplate.

Comment: Looks like the easiest solution for you is to define data type in non-record form like `newtype T = T Int deriving (Show)` and write record field accessor separately: `getT :: T -> Int; getT (T n) = n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Implementing Show by hand

The default way of implementing `Show` requires a fair amount of boilerplate. That is taken care of by [show-combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/show-combinators-0.1.0.0/docs/Text-Show-Combinators.html), reducing the code needed to the bare essentials:

```
instance Show ... where
  showPrec = flip (\(FuncType i o) -> showCon "FuncType" @| i @| o)
```

I think this solution is the simplest possible. No extensions, no typeclass magic under the hood. Just plain functional programming.

(Disclaimer: I wrote the two libraries mentioned in this post.)

### With GHC Generics

There is a generic implementation of `Show` in `generic-data`: `gshowsPrec` ([link to source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Generic.Data.Internal.Show.html#gshowsPrec)). But it shows types declared with record syntax as records.

#### Redoing the implementation

One way of course is to copy the implementation and remove the special handling of records.

```
{- 1. The usual boilerplate -}

class GShow p f where
  gPrecShows :: p (ShowsPrec a) -> f a -> PrecShowS

instance GShow p f => GShow p (M1 D d f) where
  gPrecShows p (M1 x) = gPrecShows p x

instance (GShow p f, GShow p g) => GShow p (f :+: g) where
  gPrecShows p (L1 x) = gPrecShows p x
  gPrecShows p (R1 y) = gPrecShows p y

{- 2. A simplified instance for (M1 C), that shows all constructors
      using positional syntax. The body mostly comes from the instance
      (GShowC p ('MetaCons s y 'False) f). -}

instance (Constructor c, GShowFields p f) => GShow p (M1 C c f) where
  gPrecShows p x = gPrecShowsC p (conName x) (conFixity x) x
   where
    gPrecShowsC p name fixity (M1 x)
      | Infix _ fy <- fixity, k1 : k2 : ks <- fields =
        foldl' showApp (showInfix name fy k1 k2) ks
      | otherwise = foldl' showApp (showCon cname) fields
      where
        cname = case fixity of
          Prefix -> name
          Infix _ _ -> "(" ++ name ++ ")"
        fields = gPrecShowsFields p x
```

#### Type surgery

(Section named after [my blogpost](https://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-11-26-type-surgery.html) but this thread is a much simpler situation.)

Another way is to transform the generic representation of our type to pretend that it's not declared using record syntax. Fortunately, the only difference is in a phantom type parameter, so that transformation can be as simple as `coerce` at run time.

```
unsetIsRecord ::
  Coercible (f p) (UnsetIsRecord f p) => Data f p -> Data (UnsetIsRecord f) p
unsetIsRecord = coerce

-- UnsetIsRecord defined at the end
```

The [`Data` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.3.0.0/docs/Generic-Data-Types.html#t:Data) basically creates a data type out of a generic representation (which is the inverse of what `Generic` does, in some sense). We can map a normally declared type to a `Data` type using `toData :: a -> Data (Rep a) p`.

Finally, we can directly apply the `gshowsPrec` function from the `generic-data` library to the output of `unsetIsRecord`.

```
instance Show T where
  showsPrec n = gshowsPrec n . unsetIsRecord . toData
```

---

`UnsetIsRecord` should ideally be in `generic-data`, but since it's not yet there, here is a possible implementation:

```
type family UnsetIsRecord (f :: * -> *) :: * -> *
type instance UnsetIsRecord (M1 D m f) = M1 D m (UnsetIsRecord f)
type instance UnsetIsRecord (f :+: g) = UnsetIsRecord f :+: UnsetIsRecord g
type instance UnsetIsRecord (M1 C ('MetaCons s y _isRecord) f) = M1 C ('MetaCons s y 'False) f)
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up writing as `showsPrec p (FuncType i o) = (showCon "FuncType" @| i @| o) p`